# Genetic Algorithm with numbers

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I must solve this problem: find all of the numbers between 0 and 255 that have a binary representation with the same number of 0s and 1s. For example, 240 is 11110000 and 153 is 10011001. I need to use genetic algorithms.

I have the codification, in a set of 8 bits [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and the quality function (number of 1s in X is similar to the number of 0s).

My problem is, which functions should I use as Genetic Operators? I had been thinking about that but I cant't find a function that fits well in this problem.

And another thing: will this be enough or do I need something more?

Am I targeting my problem okay? Or I must change the other functions that I have defined?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Note that this is simply the list of all permutations of `00001111`.

Comment: I know, but I need to do it with Genetic Algorithms :)

Answer (score 0):

If by Genetic Operator you mean the crossover function, I see nothing wrong to start with a
very basic crossover.

First, take two parents:

```
parent1 = [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
parent2 = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Then get a random cut point, say 3. Cut parents at this point:

```
parent1 = [0 0 0]  [1 1 1 1 1]
parent2 = [1 1 1]  [0 0 0 0 0]
```

And now recombine the two parents to get two new childs. First part of parent1 with last
part of parent2 (and so on...):

```
child1 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
child2 = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```